# Get list of php links with payload on website using Bash

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I want to download certain files from a website, but I struggle with the download links.

If the links were „simple“ I would get a list like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
urL="http://..."
wget -O webpage.txt "$urL"
LC_ALL=C sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' webpage.txt  > links.txt
```

But unfortunately the url looks like this:

```
<a href='/appl/ics.php?apid=5464646&amp;from=2022-06-23%2006%3A30%3A00&amp;to=2022-06-23%2006%3A30%3A000' class='icalLink'> LinkName </a>
```

How can I only get these "bigger" urls collected and save it to LinkName.ics? Maybe even using only curl to download all files at once?

Comment: Please use an HTML-parser, like [tag:xidel], to parse HTML!

Comment: How do you define bigger url? Was it expected content for `links.txt` for given example?

Comment: appl/ics.php?apid=5464646&amp;from=2022-06-23%2006%3A30%3A00&amp;to=2022-06-23%2006%3A30%3A000 is downloaded as ics file.